# Overriding Java System Library with newer class on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, dependencies, java-3d

I'm trying to compile and run a Java3D project on my mac and having some trouble. I'm using Eclipse. The program depends on an old version of Java3D, but even after I add the correct Jars in Eclipse it still is looking in the default system location instead.

When running my program in Eclipse, I get this issue:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup.pickAllSorted(IILjavax/media/j3d/PickShape;)[Ljavax/media/j3d/PickInfo;
 at com.sun.j3d.utils.pickfast.PickTool.pickAllSorted(PickTool.java:410)

BranchGroup.pickAllSorted does not exist in the Mac Default JRE System Library (JVM 1.6.0), but it does exist in the correct JAVA3D jars that I have included. I've added them to my buildpath, AND they are referenced above the JRE system library in Properties-Java Build Path-Order and Export. This seems like it should be the solution but it doesn't work.

I've been trying for a while and cannot get it to work. One possible lead I had was to try putting the .jars in /Library/Java/Extensions. When I do this, I instead get an OpenGL error and my program doesn't open at all, but its doing something I guess.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Eclipse, go to `Run > Run Configurations > Your Main > Arguments > VM Arguments` and add `-Xbootclasspath/p:newjava3d.jar`. This prepends newjava3d.jar to your bootclasspath, so the relevant classes will be loaded from it.

Comment: Adding this line to the Vm Arguments:

-Xbootclasspath/p:j3dcore.jar (or a:j3dcore.java)
Results in:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/opengl/util/BufferUtil
 at javax.media.j3d.JoglPipeline.<clinit>(JoglPipeline.java:5048)

Comment: You will have to install JOGL as mentioned in the `README-unzip.html` file that came with the Java3D distribution. You can find the latest Java3D distribution at https://java3d.dev.java.net/binary-builds.html

Comment: Its not mentioned in that readme, but thats it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When launching the program, try using either the `-Xbootclasspath` or the `-Xbootclasspath/a` switch to add your jars to the classpath. [See the java tool documentation.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html)